# Setting up Xebium to use Selenium RC instead ow Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I read a post about someone having problems running xebium test via fitnesse and chrome web driver. I have tried using firefox,chrome and IE.

Firefox is to slow to run the tests at all.
Chrome driver seems to have trouble interpreting xpaths that are in iframes.

I read that the chrome iframe issue could be solved by connecting xebium to an instance of Selenium RC.

So I wonder how do i connect my xebium tests to run in RC instead of using webdrivers?
I have a pom file for xebium containing some properties:

```
  <properties>
    <selenium.version>2.33.0</selenium.version>
    <fitnesse.version>20130530</fitnesse.version>
    <fitnesse.port>1337</fitnesse.port>
    <fitnesse.expiration>0</fitnesse.expiration>
    <maven-classpath-plugin.version>1.7</maven-classpath-plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <operadriver.version>1.1</operadriver.version>
    <phantomjsdriver.version>1.0.3</phantomjsdriver.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
  </properties>
```

and my SetUp in fitnesse:

```
| import |
| com.xebia.incubator.xebium |

| library |
| selenium driver fixture |

| script | selenium driver fixture |
| start browser | chrome| on url | http://www.qa04.someDomain.someTopDomain/ |
| do | open | on | /lottery|
| ensure | do | waitForPageToLoad | on | 3000 |
```

Comment: as an avid user of Selenium, I **wholeheartedly** recommend that you do not downgrade to RC.

Comment: Any suggestions to get iframes working?